# google drive API create spreadsheet with custom tabs

Tags: google-drive-api

I am creating a spreadsheet using the drive API.

```
    File fileMetadata = new File();
    fileMetadata.setName(fileName);
    fileMetadata.setParents(Collections.singletonList(folderId));
    fileMetadata.setMimeType(MIME_TYPE_SPREADSHEET);

    File file = driveService.files().create(fileMetadata)
        .setFields("id, parents, name") // properties in the response
        .execute();
```

However this creates a spreadsheet with 1 tab with title "Sheet 1". How can I create a spreadsheet with the drive API with the spreadsheet containing multiple sheets with titles that I would like to provide?

Comment: Are there some reasons that you cannot use Sheets API?

Comment: I wanted to create the Spreadsheet in a specific folder. I could not find a Sheets API that could create a file in a folder. I had to create the file and then move to a folder. Hence I choose to use the Drive API to create the file.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, Drive API cannot directly create and modify each tab in the spreadsheet, and Sheets API cannot directly create new spreadsheet to the specific folder yet. If you want to create the customized spreadsheet to the specific folder, at first, it creates the customized spreadsheet using Sheets API. Then, it moves the created spreadsheet to the specific folder using Drive API. If that is not what you want, I'm sorry.

Comment: Thanks Tanaike. For now, I have chosen to delete the default tab.

Comment: Thank you for the additional information.